# Image IO strange behavior resets the input stream

Tags: java, image, io, bufferedimage

I am seeing a strange behavior with ImageIO.read() method.

I pass the InputStream to this method and when I try to read it for the second time it fails to read and returns null.

I am trying to upload images to the Amazon S3 and I want to create 3 version of the image. The original and 2 thumbnails. My problem is that when I want to create the 2 thumbnails I need to read the InputStream using the ImageIO.read(). If I run this method 2 for the same InputStream I get the null for the second read.

I can circumvent this problem by reading only one and passing the same BufferedImage to the scaling method. However I still need the InputStream that my method gets to pass to the AmazonS3 services in other to upload the original file as well.

So my question is does anyone have any idea what happens to the input stream after ImageIO reads it for the first time?

Code sample below

```
public String uploadImage(InputStream stream, String filePath, String fileName, String fileExtension) {
    try {

        String originalKey = filePath + fileName + "." + fileExtension;
        String smallThumbKey = filePath + fileName + ImageConst.Path.SMALL_THUMB + "." + fileExtension;
        String largetThumbKey = filePath + fileName + ImageConst.Path.LARGE_THUMB + "." + fileExtension;

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream); 
        InputStream smallThumb = createSmallThumb(image, fileExtension);
        InputStream largeThumb = createLargeThumb(image, fileExtension);

        uploadFileToS3(originalKey, stream);
        uploadFileToS3(smallThumbKey, smallThumb);
        uploadFileToS3(largetThumbKey, largeThumb);

        return originalKey;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ManageUser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, you could wrap your original input stream in a [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) and use [mark()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#mark%28int%29) to save the starting position within the stream, and [reset()](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#reset%28%29) to return to it.

To fully answer your question: every stream gets read sequentially (often there is some kind of internal pointer pointing to the current position). After the first `ImageIO.read()`, the stream is read until its end, thus, any further read operation won't return any data (usually -1 to indicate the end of the stream). Using mark() you can save a certain position and later on return to it using reset().

Comment: +1 I also suggest using "markSupported()" to check if the original input stream supports mark and using the buffered stream only if the original one does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

ImageIO.read is going to read to the end of the input stream. Meaning there's no data left to read, which is why you're getting null when you try and read more data from it.

If you want to reuse the input stream, you'll have to call reset() on it; but that'll only work if the underlying InputStream implementation supports resetting, see markSupported() of InputStream.

That's the simple, but naive fix.

Keep in mind, you've already read the image into memory, so you don't really need to do that. This is a little clumsy, but you can write it out to a ByteArrayOutputStream, then build a new ByteArrayInputStream off of that.

If I were doing this, I'd probably read it into a byte array to begin with. Check out Commons IOUtils.read() for that. Then I'd build a new ByteArrayInputStream and reset() that as needed since it definitely supports marking.